# Why did lolcat stop working after installing rvm?

Tags: ruby, rvm, gem

After recently doing something that involved installing rvm, this error occurs when I try using lolcat.

```
/home/max/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': 
cannot load such file -- lolcat/version (LoadError)     from
/home/max/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'  
from /usr/games/lolcat:21:in `<main>'
```

It seems I can get lolcat working again by doing `gem install lolcat` but i think that just installs another copy of lolcat rather than fixing the existing one.  Can someone tell me what the original issue is?  Also, what's the difference between the lolcat installed from gem and the lolcat installed from apt-get?

Answer (score 4):

because lolcat is a part of ruby, by default before you install rvm, your system use the system ruby.
first, remove lolcat

```
sudo apt-get purge lolcat -y
```

then install it again by:

```
gem install lolcat
```

this working for me!